# Java usar biblioteca .DLL

Tags: java, c, dll

Estou com dificuldades para criar a interface em java, porque nao consigo perceber o cabeçalho da função em C.

Exemplo Cabeçalho função C:

```
CMOEP_API char * CALLCONV CMP_GetLastError( );
```

Agora no java tenho assim mas não sei como implementar os métodos:

```
public class DllFIles {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     CMOEP lib = new CMOEP();
        System.out.println("ERRO: " +lib.CMP_GetLastError());

    }

}
class CMOEP{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CMOEP");
    }
    public native char[] CMP_GetLastError( );
    //    CMOEP_API char * CALLCONV CMP_GetLastError( );

    public CMOEP(){}
}
```

Alguma ideia/ajuda?

Comment: Você pode aprender neste tutorial da Caelum http://blog.caelum.com.br/escrevendo-metodos-nativos-em-java-com-jni-e-jna/

Comment: Qual o nome do seu arquivo .dll ? Na sua assinatura do método em C, me parece que você está retornando um char, e na chamada nativa parece que está declarado char[].

Comment: A .dll pertence a empresa e serve para aceder a uma base de dados, por isso o nome não é importante, eu ainda nâo estou a usa-la completamente porque falta me os dados de acesso a BD, contudo como nunca usei uma biblioteca .dll queria começar a perceber para quando tiver de usar ser muito mais facil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar este projeto do Github pra facilitar sua vida: https://github.com/twall/jna

**Passo a passo:**

1. Crie um Projeto Maven
2. Crie o fonte C
3. Crie a interface Java
4. Crie a classe Java

**Fontes:**

dependência no pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Código C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(int num1, int num2){
  int resultado = num1 + num2;
  return resultado;
}
```

Interface Java

```
package jna;

import com.sun.jna.Library;

public interface SomaJNA extends Library {
  public int soma(int num1, int num2);
}
```

Classe Java

```
package jna;

import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class FazSoma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomaJNA calculadora = (SomaJNA) Native.loadLibrary("somadorJNA",
                SomaJNA.class);

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int resultado = calculadora.soma(num1, num2);
        System.out.println("A soma é: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Como fica no Projeto Eclipse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

That's All !

Comment: Muito obrigado, pelo seu exemplo parece simples, de  momento não posso testar, mas quando testar se funcionar eu marco como certa ;), só uma pergunta eu não sei usar o maven infelizmente mas se fizer o download e depois o Import da biblioteca " et.java.dev.jna " funciona igual certo?

Comment: Vale a pena aprender a usar o Maven. É muito util e muito produtivo e vale invesir algumas horas nisso. Você sempre pode fazer o download do JNA mas e se tiver outras dependências ? Você vai ter de sair baixando os outros JARs. Talvez você encontre elas neste link: [https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/dist](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/dist).

Comment: Muito obrigado @João Paraná, quanto ao Maven estou ciente da sua importância, ja tentei perceber o funcionamento mas não consegui, tenho de voltar a tentar...

Comment: Você sempre pode fazer o download do JNA mas e se tiver outras dependências ? Você vai ter de sair baixando os outros JARs. Talvez você encontre elas neste link: [https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/dist](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/dist). Faça primeiro uma tentativa baixando apenas o JAR [https://github.com/twall/jna/raw/master/dist/jna.jar](https://github.com/twall/jna/raw/master/dist/jna.jar) e veja se ocorre algum erro

Comment: Ok muito obrigado